# SQL server 2012 - how should I create a table with the same id value so that I can query it quickly?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have to create a table that will contain an IP address and a created date.

The table will have rows with the same IP address but likely different create dates. (unless they come in so fast that the create date is the same).

I will then want to query it to determine if 5 entries have been added for the given IP address. This must me very fast - performance is crucial as it will accessed threw an API (WCF web service) used by customers.

How should I design this for performance?

I've started with this but not sure that it is the best way.

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[AttemptedFailedLoginsToApi]
  (
      [AttemptedFailedLoginsToApi] [bigint] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
      [IPAddress] [varchar](250) NOT NULL,
      [CreatedDate] [datetime] NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT [AttemptedFailedLoginsToApiId_PK] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
  (
      [AttemptedFailedLoginsToApi] ASC,
      [IPAddress] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

Any ideas would be appreciated.

Regards.

Comment: A WCF API is the opposite of fast?  It's typically okay to answer in 5-10 seconds. If you'd like advise on how to optimise for a particular API call, at least include the function definition in terms of in and output parameters.

Comment: The input parameter would be the IP address, the output a Boolean indicating whether access is granted to the API. The IP may be hacking and this is an attempt to determine that. If the IP attempts it more than 5 times, then it is banned.  It will be 5 entries within a certain time frame.

Comment: You have an identity column in your table so no need for ip in primary key. Just leave AttemptedFailedLoginsToApi in primary key. Then you can add nonclustered index on ip and createddate columns if you will be filtering by thoso columns.

Comment: Giorgi - I will be filtering on justt he IP address. The created date is there to just to see when the attempt had occurred, Theoretically if the dates are right after each other, then it it is likely a hack attempt. So just having a nonclustered index on the IP address should suffice for speed. Is that correct?

Comment: To quickly search on IP Address, change the primary key so it starts with `IPAddress` instead of `AttemptedFailedLogingsToApi`.

Comment: Andomar - I will be executing a SELECT COUNT(*) from AttemptedFailedLoginsToApi where IPAddress = @attemptingIPAddress to determine if 5 rows with the same IP address exist. If I do as you suggest, will I also have to provide the identity in the WHERE clause? Sorry..kind of new to this.

Comment: I believe changing the PK to just the `IDENTITY` and adding a NCI on IPAddress would suffice as you mentioned. How do you determine the time frame? Maybe an index (or inclusion on earlier mentioned index) is needed there as well.

Answer (score 1):

Why do you need to create a table with the same id just keep id on auto increment, create a column for ip and a date column and whenever you have to query it just select your desired column.

Comment: New to this..so not sure I understand your suggestion. "just keep id on auto increment". Is that the identity column?  I believe I want to keep the same IP address rows contiguous so that querying them with the same IP address it happens quickly. I will be execuitng a SELECT COUNT(*) to determine if 5 rows with the same IP address exist.